# Spark compiles but unable to run a test program within Intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

Spark has compiled within Intellij via Maven. I am running one of the test suites. It does launch but fails at a basic scala library. What is going on?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
```

Note that this is a maven project and the tests run successfully from the command line using `mvn test`.

Here is scala library info:

[image]

Here is the project definition:

[image]

Here is the module info showing the scala 2.11 dependency:

[image]
Here is the run configuration:

[image]

Here is the result of running:

[image]

**UPDATE** I was asked about the pom.xml.  It is the pom.xml from `spark` for scala-2.11. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml

Here is the snippet

```
<profile>
  <id>scala-2.11</id>
  <activation>
    <property><name>scala-2.11</name></property>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.7</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
  </properties>
</profile>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-actors</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalap</artifactId>
    <version>${scala.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Is your scala library working properly?  That's a part of basic scala that it's not finding.  I would recommend trying to remove and then re-add the scala library in your project settings.

Comment: @soong . I already tried removing/re-adding the scala library.

Comment: What's your pom.xml look like? Does it include scala-library?

Comment: You need to post your build.sbt or pom.xml for us to be able to troubleshoot this.

Comment: jeff and @Olivier Girardot  It is the pom.xml from spark itself that can be found in the github spark repo  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml . I also put a portion of it in the OP.

Comment: I thought spark didn't support scala 2.11, only 2.10. Has that changed?

Comment: @Daenyth  Spark has supported 2.11 at least since 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Spark lib is on your class_path.

To build it run

`build/mvn -DskipTests clean package`

then  include '/assembly/target/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/spark-assembly*hadoop*-deps.jar' to your project.